# Python: getting info from file?

Tags: python

Users are prompted for the location of a file that contains multiple sets of some information: the product number, the price of the product, the day, the month, the year.
eg.

```
12345678,200,1,1,2014
23456789,150,1,1,2014
12345678,180,1,2,2014
```

I need to get the total number of prices (ie 200,150,180). How do I do so?

Comment: Is the data all on the same line? Or does `|` mean that it's one product per line?

Comment: So this requires prompting for a path, reading from the file, parsing the lines, calculating the result and printing it. Which step are you stuck on?

Comment: I added | to break it up. | means that it's entered on a new line.

I have prompted for the path and i put 'r' after it but that is as far as I have gotten

Comment: It'd be very difficult to help/answer without some code or further program details. update your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's always important to tell people [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), including snippets of any failed attempts so that they can understand what avenues you have missed. It's important because it motivates people to answer and it's important because it makes it *easier* to give high quality, relevant answers. With the current state of the question, this hasn't been achieved. If you edit the question, it's possible that the question can be prevented from being closed and the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well.

Comment: The next step would be to validate if the path the user provided is valid, and if so, the file has to be [opened](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) so it can be read from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your file, iterate over its lines with a for loop, split each line by commas and print second field.

This should work:

```
filepath = raw_input('Input file path:\n')
with open(filepath) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.split(',')[1]
```

Comment: This pseudo code looks just like real code ;-)

Comment: Python is wonderful, isn't it? :P Just forgot to edit that part after a few changes ;)